# Ordered options in Python's optparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optional-arguments

First of all, I know optparse is deprecated since version 2.7, but I only have Python 2.3 available in the machine I'm working.

The question is how to know the order in which the options were given in the command line, for instance:

```
python example.py -f foo -b bar
```

will execute first the option f and then the option b and

```
python example.py -b bar -f foo
```

will do the opposite.

The only solution I came up with after reading `optargs` documentation is to use the `callback` action to store the option **and** detect the position relative to the other options, since the `options` object doesn't seem to follow any particular order.

Do you know another (maybe better) solution to this problem?

Comment: The rules are quite clear: it's not supposed to matter.  Why are you trying to break the command-line parsing rules?  There are usually alternatives that are simpler to implement and fit with the rules better, too.  What's the background behind this question?

Comment: Your current solutions seems straightforward to me. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: The background behind the question is that the flag `-a` modifies some data, and the flag `-b` also modifies the same data in another way. Of course is not the same to apply first the function A() and then the function B() (or the other way arround). I want to be able to specify the order in which these functions are applied. 

Since the transformations A() and B() of the data are triggered by the flags `-a` and `-b`, taking into account the order will solve this problem. Maybe there is another way to do this, so I should re-formulate the question to ask for that other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's against convention to have option flags that trigger different behaviors depending on the order. But if you really want check for the order, you can just look in sys.argv

```
#assuming both -f and -b are given in cmdline and you need to check for order
index_f = sys.argv.find("-f")
index_b = sys.argv.find("-b")
if index_f < index_b: 
    # do something if -f is before -b
```

Comment: The options don't trigger different behaviours, please read edit in main question. Anyway, this will work, thanks.